# Conditional Operators(!=)(If-else Statement)

Tags: java, if-statement

Desired Output:

```
Data Type: int
Variable Name: a
Initial Value: 0
Conditional Operator: !=
Conditional Value: 5
Increment/Decrement: ++
Interval: 1
for(int a=0;a!=5;a+=1)
{
}
for(int a=1;a!=5;a+=1)
{
}
for(int a=2;a!=5;a+=1)
{
}
for(int a=3;a!=5;a+=1)
{
}
for(int a=4;a!=5;a+=1)
{
}
```

If you change the interval to 2, it should output "Infinite Loop! Try Again" and if you change the interval to 1, it should output the desired output stated above.

My program's output:

```
Data Type: int
Variable Name: a
Initial Value: 0
Conditional Operator: !=
Conditional Value: 5
Increment/Decrement: ++
Interval: 1
Infinite Loop! Try Again!
```

My code:

```
else if(inc_dec.equals("++") && conditionalOperator.equals("!="))
 {
   for(float c=initialValue;c!=conditionalValue;c+=interval)
     {
       if(initialValue == conditionalValue)
         System.out.print("for("+dataType+" "
         +varName+"="+c+";"+varName+conditionalOperator+conditionalValue+";"
         +varName+"+="+interval+"){\n}\n");
       else break;
     }
       System.out.println("Infinite Loop! Try Again!");
  }
```

P.S. The code should only use if-only statements

Comment: My guess: `if(initialValue == conditionalValue)` --> `if(c < conditionalValue)` and `else break;` --> `else {System.out.println("Infinite Loop! Try Again!"); break;}` and remove `System.out.println("Infinite Loop! Try Again!");` outside the loop.

Comment: It works but if i input in the interval 2, it'll output  `for(int a=0.0;a!=5.0;a+=2.0){
}
for(int a=2.0;a!=5.0;a+=2.0){
}
for(int a=4.0;a!=5.0;a+=2.0){
}` instead of `Infinite Loop! Try Again!`

Comment: There is no 'operator-keyword' here, or in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it!

```
else if(inc_dec.equals("++") && conditionalOperator.equals("!="))
                    {
                     for(float c=initialValue;c!=conditionalValue;c+=interval)
                     {
                      if(conditionalValue%interval == 0)
                         System.out.print("for("+dataType+" "+varName+"="+c+";"+varName+conditionalOperator+conditionalValue+";"+varName+"+="+interval+"){\n}\n");
                      else break;
                     }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Initial value of `a = 0` and if you increment variable `a` value by `2` then the condition `a!=5` will never be true.
Your `a` becomes 0,2,4,6,8...infinity (But it will never become 5). Hence you are going into infinite loop.

Comment: I know but my problem is that the output should output "Infinite Loop! Try Again!" if it's an infinite loop and if it's not infinite loop, it should output the for() statement and how the variable increments based on your data.

Comment: `for(int a=0;a!=5;a+=2)
{if(a>5) System.out.print("infinite loop");break;
}` try this out